# How Cyrillic text can be parsed with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

got a trouble with HtmlAgilityPack. I can't parse Cyrillic text, it's appears as some unknown symbols.

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
webGet.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = webGet.Load("http://vk.com/glitchhop");
HtmlNode myNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='page_wall_posts']/*[2]//div[@class='wall_post_text']");
if (myNode != null)
    return myNode.InnerText;
else return "Nothing found";
```

Also attach example of error and how that text should be looks like

[image: My application and wrong cyrilic text]
[image: Original text from the website]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is not related to HTMLAgilityPack, it is caused by incorrect encoding you're using.

Webpage you're trying to parse is encoded using `windows-1251` encoding.

So changing `webGet.OverrideEncoding` from `Encoding.UTF8` to `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` should help you.

Comment: Omg) that was helpfull. But from that I know UTF-8 is also cyrillic text. Hm, I wasn't expected that 1251 is gives me different result. Thanks!